# express, ejs, multer form handling

Tags: node.js, ejs, multer, nodemailer

I've been having trouble sending the contents of a form input:file with nodemailer. i've tried resorting to various documentation such as:

https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

sadly without much luck.

i have the code split over 3 files and have have isolated the relevant code to post here.

form.ejs:

```
<form action="/sent" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameForm" name="nameInput"  required aria-labelledby="nameLabel" autocomplete="family-name">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailForm" name="emailInput" placeholder="name@example.com" aria-labelledby="emailLabel" autocomplete="email">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneForm" name="phoneInput" placeholder="06 12 123 123" aria-labelledby="telephoneLabel" autocomplete="tel">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileForm" onchange="return fileValidation()" name="fileInput" accept=".pdf, .odt,.doc,.docx">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="messageForm" name="messageInput" rows="6" style="height: 16.275rem" aria-labelledby="textareaLabel"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input me-2" id="termsForm" name="termsInput">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

route.js:

```
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

   router.post('/sent', upload.single('fileInput'), formValidation, formHandler);

module.exports = router;
```

handler.js

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    sendmail: true,
    newline: '',
    path: '/'
});
  

// Define validation rules
const formValidation = [
    check('nameInput').isLength({ min: 2 }).isAlpha().withMessage('Name is required'),
    check('phoneInput').isNumeric().withMessage('Phone number is required'),
    check('emailInput').isEmail().withMessage('Email is not valid'),
    check('messageInput').isLength({ min: 1, max: 3000 }).withMessage('Message must be between 1 and 3000 characters'),

    // Custom file input check
    check('fileInput').custom((value, { req }) => {
        const mimetype = value.mimetype;
        if (mimetype !== 'application/pdf' && mimetype !== 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' && mimetype !== 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text' && mimetype !== 'application/msword') {
          throw new Error('Invalid file type');
        }
        return true;
      }),

    check('termsInput').equals('on').withMessage('Terms must be accepted'),
];

    // Define form handler
    const formHandler = (req, res) => {
    // Check for validation errors
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    // Send email
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '',
        to: '',
        subject: `Form: ${req.body.nameInput}}`,
        text: `Name: ${req.body.nameInput}\nEmail: ${req.body.emailInput} \nMessage: ${req.body.messageInput}`,
        attachments: [{
            filename: req.file.filename,
            content: req.file.buffer
          }]
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).render('layout', { pageTitle: "Form error", errorMessage: error.message });
        }
        else {
            return res.status(200).render('layout', { pageTitle: "Form sent" });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = { formValidation, formHandler };
```

it's possible i've created a variable naming mismatch in anonymizing it. the typeError i couldn't seem to get around was the email attachment.

any help would be apriciated.